# Ошибка Clion ( SFML , Cmake )

Tags: c++, cmake, sfml, clion

При компиляции проекта высвечивает такую **ошибку** -

```
 CMake Error at /usr/local/lib/cmake/SFML/SFMLConfig.cmake:139 (message):
  Requested SFML configuration (Static) was not found
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:14 (find_package)
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:14 (find_package):
  Found package configuration file:

    /usr/local/lib/cmake/SFML/SFMLConfig.cmake

  but it set SFML_FOUND to FALSE so package "SFML" is considered to be NOT
  FOUND.
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/Users/macos/Desktop/COVID19/cmake-build-debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
[Failed to reload]
```

*https://i.stack.imgur.com/5rjJ5.jpg*
**Вот что в CmakeLists.txt -**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.7)

project(COVID19)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++17 -static")
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

add_library(vemath STATIC vemath.h vemath.cpp)

add_executable(COVID19 main.cpp)

# SFML Librares
set(SFML_DIR "D:/Libraries/SFML/lib/cmake/SFML")
set(SFML_STATIC_LIBRARIES TRUE)
find_package(SFML 2.5.1 COMPONENTS graphics audio REQUIRED)
include_directories(${SFML_INCLUDE_DIR})

target_link_libraries(COVID19 sfml-audio sfml-network sfml-graphics sfml-window sfml-system vemath)
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как решить эту проблему. Папку с SFML закидывал в сам проект ничего не меняется.
Думаю, что ошибка в set SFML_DIR но не знаю куда указывать правильный путь ( У меня Mac OS, а там D: )

Comment: Вы уверены, что статические библиотеки на MacOS собраны? Попробуйте убрать `set(SFML_STATIC_LIBRARIES TRUE)`. https://en.sfml-dev.org/forums/index.php?topic=26837

Comment: @Tocic теперь только вот такая ошибка "ld: library not found for -lcrt0.o
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)"

Comment: Опция `-static` не работает для MacOS. https://stackoverflow.com/q/3801011/6944845

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Надо убрать `set(SFML_STATIC_LIBRARIES TRUE)`. Также опция -static не работает для MacOS.

en.sfml-dev.org/forums/index.php?topic=26837

stackoverflow.com/q/3801011/6944845